# Profile.getCurrentProfile() returns null after logging in (FB API v4.0)

Tags: android, facebook

For some reason `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` shows up null at times right after logging into FaceBook, using FB API v4.0.

This is causing problems for me in my app because I can't display my next `Activity` with `Profile` being null.

The reason I say it's null sometimes is because if I close out of my app and re-open it, I'm able to get to my next `Activity`, but if I'm not already logged in, and then login, `Profile` is null. It seems it is for a short period.

Is there a work around or fix to this?

Comment: Are you sure you have implemented profiletracker?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Like [Hardy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642759/profile-getcurrentprofile-returns-null-after-logging-in-fb-api-v4-0/29652674#comment47426932_29642759), you have to create an instance of `ProfileTracker` which will start tracking profile updates, (i.e `ProfileTracker.onCurrentProfileChanged()` will be called when the user's profile finishes being fetched).

Following is the complete code that you'd need to login to FB and get the user's profile:

```
LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_facebook);
loginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile");
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
loginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        if(Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
            mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                    Log.v("facebook - profile", currentProfile.getFirstName());
                    mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                }
            };
            // no need to call startTracking() on mProfileTracker
            // because it is called by its constructor, internally.
        }
        else {
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            Log.v("facebook - profile", profile.getFirstName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.v("facebook - onCancel", "cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        Log.v("facebook - onError", e.getMessage());
    }
});
```

You must override your Activity's or Fragment's `onActivityResult()` as below:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if you don't add following block,
    // your registered `FacebookCallback` won't be called
    if (mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        return;
    }
}
```

### Edit:

Code updated with [Alex Zezekalo's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642759/profile-getcurrentprofile-returns-null-after-logging-in-fb-api-v4-0/29652674#comment54613513_29652674) to only call `mProfileTracker.startTracking();` if `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` returns null.

Comment: Why does the tracker have to be in the onsuccess method? It seems to me it should be running from anywhere.

Comment: @LaurentGorse good question. I don't remember exactly but I think it was because Facebook had to login and fetch the profile.

Comment: After the second launch 'onSuccess'  will not call. Then how can i get the profile information

Comment: You should try to refresh your token instead. See my answer - [Refresh FB token in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33151438/1276636).

Comment: A simple Profile name. In that i answer i cant find the Profile Information

Comment: @user3607798 Alright. One way is to call `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);
  LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` before making this login request (as in this current answer, not the linked one). There sure will be more elegant solutions for it though.

Comment: I want to add a bit: before starting profile tracking you should check if current profile is null because in some cases current profile might not be null and tracker callback must not be fired

Comment: @Sufian did you forgot to call mProfileTracker.startTracking() ?

Comment: @Weizhi the constructor of `ProfileTracker` itself calls `startTracking()`. I'll add a comment to the good, however.

Comment: what is the use of the variable profile on the line: "protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2)" ????

Comment: @user1090751 I've updated the method signature. You can read more about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/4.4/class/ProfileTracker/

Answer (score 20):

Following to Sufian's answer, you can also save the new profile to Profile class:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
            this.stopTracking();
            Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);

        }
    };
    profileTracker.startTracking();
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried but I guess if you are not calling `stopTracking()` before `Profile.setCurrentProfile()`, it would start an infinite loop.

Comment: Didn't thing of this before. Will not `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` return the same object as the param `currentProfile`? I mean, `setCurrentProfile()` seems unnecessary here. Don't you think?

Comment: As I see from source code of Facebook SDK Broadcast receiver passing result to interface, you can see it in com.facebook.ProfileTracker.class, so I think it's necessary to setCurrentProfile with a new profile.

Comment: I put `Profile profile1 = Profile.getCurrentProfile();` inside `onCurrentProfileChanged()`, it returned me the non-null profile object. Seems like it is not necessary to do it in **FB SDK v4.5.0**.

Comment: Sulfan: Did you get a currentProfile or an oldProfile ?

Comment: `oldProfile` was null but `currentProfile` was same as `Profile.getCurrentProfile()`.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook loads the profile information asynchronously, so even after you get your result from the login callback, Profile.getCurrentProfile() will return null.

However, every time the user logs in through Facebook (the first time and every subsequent time) his profile will change and will fire the profiletracker. This is where you must call the profile.

Here is how you should structure your code. You must listen for the ProfileTracker to update in order to update your user properties - avoid calling getCurrentProfile outside the tracker during the login process:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile1) {


 //Listen for changes to the profile or for a new profile: update your
 //user data, and launch the main activity afterwards. If my user has just logged in,
 //I make sure to update his information before launching the main Activity.

                Log.i("FB Profile Changed", profile1.getId());
                updateUserAndLaunch(LoginActivity.this);


            }
        };
        profileTracker.startTracking();

        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                    AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                    AccessToken currentAccessToken) {




//Check that the new token is valid. This tracker is fired
//when the user logs in the first time and afterwards any time he interacts with 
//the Facebook API and there is a change in his permissions.

                if (!accessTokenIsValid(currentAccessToken)){
                    Log.i("FB Token Updated", String.valueOf(currentAccessToken.getPermissions()));
                    requestLogin();

                }
            }
        };
        // User already has a valid access token? Then take the user to the main activity
        if (accessTokenIsValid(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken())){
               launchApp();
        }else{
//Show the Facebook login page
            requestLogin();
        }

    }
```

The key here is that you should not call Profile.getcurrentprofile from the login callback (either LoginManager,registercallback or loginButton.registercallback) - the values are not reliable. Set up the tracker and rely on it firing at the opportune time in order to get updated profile info.

Comment: This seems like another way to go about, however I think this has few issues that I can think of. What if the login fails due to **connectivity/timeout** or the **user cancels the login**?

Answer (score 0):

I have a simpler suggestion than the other answers here.

There is **no need** to register a login callback with:

```
registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() { ... }
```

Instead, whenever you need user data (like on button click) - start tracking profile changes with:

```
new ProfileTracker() {
    @Override
    protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile profile) {
        stopTracking();

        Log.d(TAG, profile.getFirstName());
        Log.d(TAG, profile.getLastName());
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large", profile.getId()));
    }
}.startTracking();
```

And then start the Facebook login process by:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getContext(), Arrays.asList("public_profile"));
```

For the above code to work you of course need to prepare the usual stuff in your Activity:

```
private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (FacebookSdk.isFacebookRequestCode(requestCode) &&
            mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to modify the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started) file.