# Facebook SDK: Why does Profile.getCurrentProfile() always return null for the first time?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-login

I am implementing Facebook login in my Android app using LoginButton class provided in Facebook SDK.
Everything kind of works after following instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3). The only thing I am doing differently in my app, is that I have added the login button on a fragment as against the activity itself, to avoid polluting the login activity with a lot of code.
But here's a problem:
I want to get the user's public profile information. And I do that using `Profile.getCurrentProfile()` call. Here's the complete code:

```
// Called in onCreate:
    private void attemptLogin() {

            mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback = getFacebookCallback();
            mLoginButton.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mFacebookCallback);
        }
```

And the mFacebookCallback code is this:

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> getFacebookCallback() {
        return new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {

                        @Override
                        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {

                            if (currentProfile != null && oldProfile != null) {
                                mProfile = currentProfile;
                                // Get the new email and fire the home page of the activity, when email is available
                                requestUserEmail();
                            }

                            mProfileTracker.stopTracking();

                        }
                    };

                    mProfileTracker.startTracking();

                    if (null != loginResult.getAccessToken()) {

                        String userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();

                        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully Logged-In to Facebook");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logged-In to Facebook:" + userId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        mProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

                        // Now that login is successful, email can be requested
                        requestUserEmail();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cancelled Log-In to Facebook");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled Log-In to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error while Logging-In to Facebook");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error while Logging-In to Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            };
    }
```

I get AccessToken and even email just fine. But for the first installation of the app, Profile.getCurrentProfile() always returns null.

I also observed that `onCurrentProfileChanged()` is never really called, as I was expecting it to be called the first time the login attempt is made. I am not sure if `onCurrentProfileChanged()` related code should be within `onSuccess()`. But it seems people have had more luck by doing that, as per the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642759/facebook-login-api-4-0-profile-getcurrentprofile-null-when-logged-in).

What am I doing wrong here? What do I need to do to make sure that I get the profile information in the first go?

Comment: this is also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642759/profile-getcurrentprofile-returns-null-after-logging-in-fb-api-v4-0

Answer (score 1):

After a few minutes of debugging I found out the obvious issue. In  the code below:

```
if (currentProfile != null && oldProfile != null) {
    mProfile = currentProfile;
   // Get the new email and fire the home page of the activity, when email is available
   requestUserEmail();
}
```

The first time, oldProfile is always null. Therefore, mProfile is never set to current profile.

Secondly, I am not sure if it makes any difference, but changing

```
mLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_friends", EMAIL));
```

to

```
mLoginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", EMAIL));
```

might have helped.

Also, just for the sake of completion, it is sufficient to request for email ( call to `requestUserEmail()` function in this case) only once in `onCurrentProfileChanged` is sufficient

Comment: I will post it on git. By the way, did you enable the single sign-on switch on your Facebook app? That seemed to help. You can do that after creating the app on Facebook developer portal and going into its settings

Comment: Yes I did. Btw I managed to have code working by removing `Profile.getCurrentProfile();` from `onSuccess()` method and moving rest of the code to `onCurrentProfileChanged()`.

Comment: Great! :) Well, that's kind of what I did too. I am not relying on getCurrentProfile() anymore. But instead on ProfileTracker to update the profile info, if and when it changes