# Android: Profile info is NULL for first time logging in using Facebook SDK 4.1

Tags: java, android, facebook

When logging the first time the profile is null and after that it works.
Am I using the Profile Tracker and AccessToken Tracker correctly?
I am not using Profile.getcurrentprofile() as I was told it will not work. NEW ERROR: When I am logged out of Facebook and I try to login to my android app by pressing the Facebook Login Button the login screen opens but I receive an error:

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.stopTracking()' on a null object reference**

This question is similar to these questions but the solution does not work and there is no solution provided.

[Profile.getCurrentProfile() returns null after logging in (FB API v4.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642759/facebook-login-api-4-0-profile-getcurrentprofile-null-when-logged-in?lq=1)

[Facebook SDK: Why does Profile.getCurrentProfile() always return null for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425442/facebook-sdk-why-does-profile-getcurrentprofile-always-return-null-for-the-fi)

My UPDATED code is below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

}


@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


    LoginButton  loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));

    // If using in a fragment
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    // Other app specific specialization

    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                    // Set the access token using
                    // currentAccessToken when it's loaded or set.
                    Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
                    AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(currentAccessToken);

                }
            };

            accessTokenTracker.startTracking();

            profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                @Override
                protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
                    // App code
                    if(currentProfile!=null)
                    {
                        Profile.setCurrentProfile(currentProfile);
                        profile = currentProfile;
                    }

                }
            };

            profileTracker.startTracking();

           // App code
            //token you have been granted to access the facebook sever
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            //user's profile thats login

            profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            final Bundle extras = new Bundle();

            //error is HERE PROFILE IS NULL
            extras.putString(EXTRA_PROFILENAME, profile.getFirstName());   
            extras.putString(EXTRA_PROFILEID, profile.getId());

            .... rest code
           }

       }



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
   // accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}

public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
    profileTracker.stopTracking();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `ProfileTokenTracker` and `AccessTokenTracker` in your `onSuccess()` method and start it there and then stop tracking in `onDestroy()` or `onStop()`. That way you start getting data from users profile when he is logged in. This is my `onSuccess()` method:

```
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

        accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken accessToken, AccessToken accessToken1) {

            }
        };
        accessTokenTracker.startTracking();

        profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile1) {

            }
        };
        profileTracker.startTracking();

        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (profile != null) {
        //get data here
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi @laky.brat I moved both methods to the onsuccess() and had the same implementation as before except I remove the stop tracking and place it on the onDestroy() and onStop(). Should trackers be blank like yours? I receive this error 'void com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.stopTracking()' on a null object reference at onStop()

Comment: the error occurs because I am using profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();. This occurs when I log out of the facebook app and try to login on my app. I press the login button which opens up the facebook login screen which is when I get the error. So what should I do with the AccessTokenTracker?

Comment: @akalanta please take a look at this image [link](http://community.monogame.net/uploads/default/820/fcaf25c811f85f46.jpg) and then figure out when should you stop `AccessTokenTracker`. Best practice is to stop it in `onStop()` method, because you may clsoe the app and come back later and then users data will be saved. You can use `SharedPrefferences` to store data and when there is no internet user will be able to see his picture, name etc.

Comment: @akalanta If you stop `AccessTokenTracker` in `onStop()` then delete the line you stopped it in `onDestroy()`, because it can't stop the already stopped tracker so that is the reason you get `NullPointerException`. Hope this helps! And in the future if you get an error please first take a look at logcat.

Comment: I removed the accesstokentraker from OnDestroy() but the same error still occurred  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.stopTracking()' on a null object` reference

Comment: @akalanta Remove `accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();` from `onCurrentAccessTokenChanged` and tell me if it helps.

Comment: that was already removed. This error only occurs when I log out of the facebook app and open my app to login. It opens the facebook login screen once the Facebook Login Button is pressed and that's when the error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Try to move

```
accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
profileTracker.startTracking();
Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
```

into onSuccess() method.